# Sqlite Database Connection in Phonegap

Tags: cordova

I made an sql database using sqlite. It contains id, name, Address values. In my app I have three text boxes. I want to connect that database with my Phonegap app. How is it possible? Does anyone know?

Comment: If you have created the table you should already know how to connect to the database? Or am I missing something? Some more detail and some code examples would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for the PhoneGap Storage API?

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

Answer (score 0):

u need to use sqlite plugin to copy your prepopulated database in your app. Then only you can utilise that database.